# ARM SWP instruction and cache

Tags: arm

I've been reading about synchronisation methods in ARM processors. I came across some question regarding this area. If I'm using SWP instruction I need to give some address in memory as third parameter. But if the system is multicore ARM - what in case when the contents of this memory address is cached in other processor's cache?

Will the cache be invalidated at this case or something else will happen? Anyone can explain it?

Comment: although still present arm discourages the use of SWP for multicore, instead use LDREX/STREX for multicore (SWP for unicore as LDREX/STREX is not required to be supported by the chip for unicore).

Comment: basically keep digging, and BTW dont use linux sources as a guide.

Comment: if you are really wanting to share a resource (a memory location with which to do a lock with another core for example) does it make sense to cache that address (space) for any of the cores?  Granted LDREX/STREX works great within ARMs logic, bypass the caches and you end up in vendor logic and 1) did they implement exclusive access at all and 2) does it work right.

Comment: Understand ldrex/strex IS NOT A REPLACEMENT FOR swp.  Ldrex/strex is for sharing information between cores.  You will find plenty of misunderstanding there and misapplication of ldrex/strex.  Those applications happen to work because the cache is on and ARM supports ldrex/strex in its own cache logic so if you are using swp to talk to yourself (within one core) and replace that with ldrex/strex it happens to work (so long as the cache line(s) dont get evicted).  Keep reading the arm documentation...

Answer (score -1):

As told on some answers, `SWP` is not used anymore, even on quite old CPUs (Deprecated on all Cortex-A CPUs).

Although not a replacement, `LDREX/STREX` has to be used instead. The Cortex-A CPUs have the capability to directly share data in their L1 caches (See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocole_MESI) without the need for invalidation.